# Use Scrapy to combine data from multiple AJAX requests into a single item

Tags: scrapy

What is the best way to crawl pages with content coming from multiple AJAX requests? It looks like I have the following options (given that AJAX URLs are already known):

1. Crawl AJAX URLs sequentially passing the same item between requests
2. Crawl AJAX URLs concurrently and output each part as a separate item
       with a shared key (e.g. source URL)

What is the most common practice? Is there a way to get a single item at the end, but allow some AJAX requests to fail w/o compromising the rest of the data?

Answer (score 1):

scrapy is built for concurrency and statelessness, so if point 2 is possible, it is always preferred, from both speed and memory consumption aspects.

in case requests must be serialized, consider accumulate items in request meta field

Answer (score 1):

Check [scrapy-inline-requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-inline-requests). It allows to smoothly process multiple nested requests in a response handler.